# Accessing Android Files and Database Directly on the device if rooted?

Tags: android

When developing for Android I prefer just working with a real device plugged in most of the time since the Android emulators are such total garbage.  The one pain point is when I want to access files and sqlite databases though.  I believe with the adb shell it is possible to pull the database across, but this isn't a very convenient process.

I'm wondering if there are any tools on the market that allow you to see the database in real time, even if it requires rooting a device I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there are no tools that will let you see the db real time. You will need to get the db from the device and the see it on your system. You will have to root the phone and get SuperUser permission to access app databases. The database will (after getting root) then be available in the `/data/data/com.your.application/databases` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You don't have any tools to see the database in real times. But its achievable in rooted device. If your device is rooted just install root explorer app in it. and then browse for your package name in data/data/  location. There you will find out all the internal memory files including database files. hope this helps you.